# Supporting Carthage for framework with dependency?

Tags: carthage

I want make my framework supporting Carthage. A cocoa framework project have been create.

The problem is my framework depends another framework (carthage supported). If I don't add the framework file to the project, how do pass building.

Comment: I'm facing same problem dude and looking for a solution

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: yeah did you figure this out!?